# 2D-arrays ND-arrays appear to index differently in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

As part of a larger project, I need to be able to make an orthogonal "projection" of a scalar-field in each of its N-dimensions. (Effectively I want to take the mean of the data in every dimension except the "dimension of projection").  Below is a simplified (but complete and runnable) excerpt of the relevant code that works.... *except* when the projection dimension is the 0-th or 1-st axis. When this is the case, the code appears behave as if these two dimensions have been swapped. I need help to understand why this is happening, and what the best way is to reconcile this behavior so that the program works consistently no matter which dimension is indexed.

```
from pylab import *
import scipy.interpolate

def projectAxis(d,projection_dim,nDim) :
    """calculate (and plot) the mean across all axes, except for the
    projection dimension

    """
    all_axes_except_projection_dim = range(nDim)
    all_axes_except_projection_dim.remove(projection_dim)
    plot(mean(d,axis=tuple(all_axes_except_projection_dim)))
    ylim(0,1); yticks([0,1]);

def test(nDim,varies_in_dim,col=1) :
    """Generate a gradient in nDim-dimensional space, and project it in
    each dimension. """

    ## generate 1000 randomly distributed coordinates
    xs = np.random.rand(1000,nDim) 
    ## generate a value to be associated with each coordinate.  The
    ## value is assigned such that it correlates (exactly) with a
    ## particular dimension / axis of the data. The particular
    ## dimension is assigned by the parameter 'varies_in_dim'.
    z = xs[:,varies_in_dim] 

    ## interpolate, to create a regular n-dimensional mesh
    lattice_width = 11 
    m_points = [linspace(0,1,lattice_width)]*nDim
    interpolation_points = tuple(np.meshgrid(*m_points))
    zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata(xs, z, interpolation_points, method='nearest')

    def plotProjection(axis,nDim) :
        projectAxis(zi,axis,nDim)
        if col == 3 :
            ylabel('axis=%d' %(axis))
            gca().yaxis.set_label_position("right")

    # if there are sufficient dimensions to display
    # variation in the specified dimension...
    if nDim > varies_in_dim :
        for d in xrange(4) :
            if nDim > d :
                subplot2grid((rows,cols),(d,col))
                plotProjection(d,nDim)
                if d == 0 :
                    title('%d-D space' %(nDim))


figure(figsize=(7,8))
rows,cols = 4,4
varies_in_dim = 1
suptitle('Data should only substantially vary along axis %d' %(varies_in_dim) )

test(2,varies_in_dim,col=0)
test(3,varies_in_dim,col=1)
test(4,varies_in_dim,col=2)
test(5,varies_in_dim,col=3)

show()
```

When run with `varies_in_dim = 2` (or for higher values), the output is what I would expect. For each test case (spaces of 3,4 or 5 dimensions), the only projection that shows variation is the 2nd dimension (where dimensions are indexed from 0). Here is the output for `varies_in_dim = 2`, which is correct:

[image: Correct output for variation in dimension 2]

But when `varies_in_dim = 1`, the output shows variation in dimension 0...and vice versa: when `varies_in_dim = 0`, the output shows variation in dimension 1. The following image shows the output for  `varies_in_dim = 1`, which **wrongly shows the variation as occuring in dimension 0**.

[image]

What am I missing? How should my program be reorganized to work consistently?

Comment: I wonder: am I using `scipy.interpolate.griddata` wrong?

Comment: Not sure if this is the reason (tl;dr), but: [meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html#numpy.meshgrid) by default swaps the first two dimensions, to please Matlab users. `meshgrid(..., indexing="ij")` does not swap the first two dimensions.

Comment: That fixes it. Thank you.  My dislike of matlab has intensified! How can this inconsistent behavior be the default? Shocking!

Comment: So does contourf and imshow do similar "behind-the-scenes" axis swapping? Can you point me to the documentation on this? Thanks.

Comment: @pv. perhaps you can post your comment as the answer...

Comment: Yeah, @pv. if you post this as the answer, I will accept and the questions can be closed. Thanks again.